# How can we call multiple threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any way to call a thread after finishing the work of another thread? I just want to call three threads back to back as work gets finished of previous thread.

I'm trying this

```
public class TestThreads {
public static void main (String [] args) {
MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
Thread first = new Thread(r);
Thread second = new Thread(r);
Thread third = new Thread(r);
first.start();
second.start();
third.start();
}
}
```

Is it correct way??

Comment: If you want sequential execution, then why create new threads?..

Comment: For high CPU-tasks which need to be run in the background.

Comment: Why don't then use one `Thread` and its `run()` method can have all that is there in `run()` of first, second and third Thread in sequence. Why bring unnecessary complexity

Comment: @AnshulTyagi - All your thread will have a priority of 5. And they will not run in the background. They are normal threads

Comment: What about if everything is related to each other? @Nitin

Comment: @TheLostMind - What should I do for that?

Comment: If you mean these Threads have dependencies among each other? probably you are not asking the right question here

Comment: @AnshulTyagi:- What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I've got what I needed.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi - You are trying to run *background threads* sequentially. If this is some kind of *testing exercise*, then its fine, else, the design looks really fishy. Even *deamon* threads won't help you as you want to wait for each of them to finish

Comment: Yes, its testing because I've never worked with multiple threads.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi - Oh. Then you could use `join()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [Thread.Join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of
>   another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,
>
> ```
> t.join();
> ```
>
> causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread
>   terminates. Overloads of join allow the programmer to specify a
>   waiting period. However, as with sleep, join is dependent on the OS
>   for timing, so you should not assume that join will wait exactly as
>   long as you specify.
>
> Like sleep, join responds to an interrupt by exiting with an
>   InterruptedException.

So it would be like

```
first.start();
first.join();
second.start();
second.join();
third.start();
```

On a side note you can refer this [Thread join() method in Java with example](http://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/thread-join-method-in-java-with-example/)

Answer (score 2):

> Joins
>
> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of
>   another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,
>
> t.join(); causes the current thread to pause execution until t's
>    thread terminates. Overloads of join allow the programmer to specify a
>    waiting period. However, as with sleep, join is dependent on the OS
>    for timing, so you should not assume that join will wait exactly as
>    long as you specify.
>
> Like sleep, join responds to an interrupt by exiting with an
>    InterruptedException.

Here is a simple change in your code

```
 public class TestThreads {
     public static void main (String [] args) {
       MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
         Thread first = new Thread(r);
         Thread second = new Thread(r);
         Thread third = new Thread(r);
         first.start();
         first.join();  // will wait for the first thread to terminate
         second.start();
         second.join();  // will wait for the second thread to terminate
         third.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why are you using thread? If you don't want the parallel processing, You should go ahead with sequential execution.**

If you still want to use threads you can use the `join` method.

```
first.start();
first.join();
second.start();
second.join();
third.start()
```